# Small doubt about the connecting homomorphism on the long homology sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology

When you consider the long homology sequence (of spaces $A,X$ , with $A$ subspace of $X$) you need to define an homomorphism from $H_q(X,A)$ to $H_{q-1}(A)$ to obtain the long homology sequence from the short one involving $0 \to H_q(A) \to H_q(X) \to H_q(X,A) \to0$.

The homomorphism you construct from $H_q(X,A) \to H_{q-1}(A)$ is the border homomorphism (it is an easy check that it is well defined in the quotient and its image can be thought in $H_{q-1}(X,A)$).

The main problem I see is that the homomorphism you construct is the zero one (and it does not make sense that you construct it if later is homomorphism zero). I mean, you know that the map from $H_q(A) \to H_q(X)$ is injective and the one from $H_q(X) \to H_q(X,A)$ surjective so by exactness you conclude that the kernel of this ''border'' map is the hole $H_q(X,A)$.

Any idea?

Comment: It's not true that the map $H_q(A) \to H_q(X)$ is injective, neither is it true that the map $H_q(X) \to H_q(X, A)$ is surjective.

Comment: In fact the boundary map measures precisely the extent to which both of your claims fail to be true! That's why it's so important.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The map on the **chain level** $C_*(A) \to C_*(X)$ might be injective, but the induced map on **homology** $H_*(A) \to H_*(X)$ need not be.  As an example, set $X = \Bbb R^2, A = S^1$.  Then the map $\Bbb Z \cong H_1(S^1) \to H_1(\Bbb R^2) \cong 0$ is necessarily zero.

Similarly, the map on homology  $H_*(X) \to H_*(X, A)$ need not be surjective.  Consider $X = [0,1]$ and $A = \{0,1\}$.  Then $H_1(X) \cong 0$ but $H_1(X,A) \cong \Bbb Z \not\cong 0$.

In both of these examples, you can check that the boundary map on homology is nontrivial.